# Batch converting EPS to BMP, PNG and SVG in one go

Tags: batch-processing, eps, file-conversion

Does anyone know if there is a way to batch convert EPS files into BMP, PNG and SVG all in one go rather than doing in three different stages?
I currently use a combination of Illustrator and Photoshop so that I don't lose too much quality of the image. It would save a great deal of time if these converions could be done in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in Affinity Designer I can set up multi-format, multi-parameter export slices in the Export Persona which could accomplish *most* of this, and AFAIK you can do similar in Illustrator with the Export to Screens workflow.

**Illustrator:**

[image]
[image]

**Affinity Designer:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

But... in both cases, though they *will* save raster files as well as vector formats like svg and pdf, I ***don't*** think **.bmp** is a format either will happily export - they will export formats more commonly used in the graphics world - so .png, .jpg, and in Affinity Designer's case, add .tiff, .psd & .exr to that list... but neither lists .bmp. You will have to accomplish a batch conversion outside of either of these tools from say .png-24 to .bmp.